# svg fill background image fit to the screen?

Tags: css, svg

I am adding SVG fill with a background image. But it is not fit the image properly. It is looking like my screenshot http://take.ms/8cloN

```
<svg width="897px" height="452px" viewBox="0 0 897 452" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.0.4 (8054) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>IPAD 2</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>

  <defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <image xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534002778889-3f1b078de59b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a2e808d0d3560da6d4845fe7e7bfc19d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" x="0" y="0" />
  </pattern>
</defs>


    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="IPAD" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(681.000000, 55.000000)" stroke="#7E89A3">
            <path d="M202.986,317 L12.097,317 C5.462,317 0.083,311.623 0.083,304.99 L0.083,12.093 C0.083,5.46 5.461,0.083 12.097,0.083 L202.986,0.083 C209.622,0.083 215,5.46 215,12.093 L215,304.99 C215,311.623 209.622,317 202.986,317 Z" id="bezel" stroke-width="2" fill="#FDFDFD" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            <path d="M202.986,317 L12.097,317 C5.462,317 0.083,311.623 0.083,304.99 L0.083,12.093 C0.083,5.46 5.461,0.083 12.097,0.083 L202.986,0.083 C209.622,0.083 215,5.46 215,12.093 L215,304.99 C215,311.623 209.622,317 202.986,317 Z" id="bezel-2" stroke-width="2" fill="#FDFDFD" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            <rect id="screen" fill="url(#img1)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="17" y="32" width="181.999" height="252.917"></rect>
            <circle id="lock" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="108.021" cy="300.021" r="8.021"></circle>
            <circle id="camera" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="106.99" cy="16.99" r="2.99"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="Laptop" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(1.000000, 1.000000)" stroke="#8492A5">
            <path d="M594,0 L98,0 C84.50415,0 73,11.0738184 73,24.7901127 L73,351.027995 L619,351.027985 L619,24.7901127 C618.999971,11.0728209 607.537479,0 594,0 Z" id="bezel" stroke-width="2" fill="#FEFEFE" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            <circle id="webcam" stroke-width="2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="347" cy="19" r="4"></circle>
            <g id="bottom" transform="translate(0.000000, 351.000000)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                <path d="M640.812,31.01 L51.288,31.01 C20.641,31.01 0,20.494 0,16.022 L0,2.428 C0,1.084 1.335,0 2.995,0 L689.104,0 C690.766,0 692.103,1.084 692.103,2.428 L692.103,16.557 C692.096,20.092 676.112,31.01 640.812,31.01 Z" id="Shape" stroke-width="2" fill="#FDFDFD"></path>
                <path d="M0.5,14.5 L690.242676,14.5" id="Line" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
            </g>
            <rect id="screen" fill="url(#img1)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="95" y="39" width="501.073853" height="292.009"></rect>
            <path d="M421,352 L421,355.087 C421,357.288 416.666719,357.952714 413.386719,357.952714 L278.815286,357.952714 C275.364286,357.952714 271,357.289 271,355.087 L271,352" id="touchpad" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="iphone" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(576.000000, 177.000000)" stroke="#7E89A3">
            <path d="M130,257.964 C130,266.797 122.809,273.956 113.938,273.956 L16.063,273.956 C7.192,273.956 0.001,266.797 0.001,257.964 L0.001,16.073 C0.001,7.24 7.192,0.081 16.063,0.081 L113.938,0.081 C122.809,0.081 130,7.24 130,16.073 L130,257.964 L130,257.964 Z" id="bezel" stroke-width="2" fill="#FDFDFD" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            <rect id="screen" fill="url(#img1)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="9" y="36" width="111.93" height="199.084"></rect>
            <path d="M77,25.746 C77,26.381 76.561,26.893 76.02,26.893 L55.918,26.893 C55.376,26.893 54.938,26.38 54.938,25.746 L54.938,23.166 C54.938,22.531 55.377,22.019 55.918,22.019 L76.02,22.019 C76.561,22.019 77,22.532 77,23.166 L77,25.746 L77,25.746 Z" id="speaker" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            <circle id="camera" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="66" cy="12" r="3"></circle>
            <ellipse id="lock" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="65.04" cy="254.001" rx="10.04" ry="10.001"></ellipse>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want it like my screenshot http://take.ms/ViaOB is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `pattern` tag, replace `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` with `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`. Then add `height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the `image` tag inside your `pattern` tag. Like this:

```
<pattern id="img1" id="pattern1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534002778889-3f1b078de59b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a2e808d0d3560da6d4845fe7e7bfc19d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" x="0" y="0" />
  </pattern>
```

Comment: @Khandaker I beg you please. Don't stretch your images like you originally asked.  Keep the aspect ratio of the original image.  Try using `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` instead..

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking about it, But I am trying to build a system; Eg, If someone uploads an image and I will insert it to a Mockup and give them a link to download that image with the mockup.

Comment: @KhandakerIkrama did this answer help you? If so could you pick it as best asnwer?